# JAXB + MOXy: Extracting a List<String> from elements' attributes?

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a XML file containing

```
    <jaxbBean file="A.groovy"/>
    <jaxbBean file="B.groovy"/>
```

Now I'd like to get a `List<String>` out of that, containing `"A.groovy", "B.groovy"`.

I've tried (and expected to work):

```
@XmlPath("jaxbBean/@file")
List<String> jaxbBeansClasses;
```

But that didn't match anything (contained null).

Is MOXy capable of doing this so simply? Or do I have to introduce an extra class?

(I don't want to change the XML syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings look correct, below is a full example.  Since you are annotating the field be sure you have `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

**Domain Model (Root)**

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlPath("jaxbBean/@file")
    List<String> jaxbBeansClasses;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17104179/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <jaxbBean file="A.groovy"/>
    <jaxbBean file="B.groovy"/>
</root>
```